# Setting sender address in Exchange 365 notifications

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, rules

We are running Office 365 including Exchange.

I've set up a rule to delete messages with attachments with a certain extension, and send a notification to the recipient. This is done with two separate rules - see screenshot:

(Sorry about the link: SE won't allow me to post an image with this account yet)

[Exchange Rule screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtBer.png)

The question is this: **How can I set the sender address that's used for the notification?**

Currently these notifications appear to come from one of the managers and we'd like to set it to something neutral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run below command to change the sender address for system-generated messages and notifications sent to message senders that exist outside your Microsoft Exchange Online organization.

```
Set-TransportConfig -ExternalPostmasterAddress manager@domain.com
```

For more details: [Configure the external postmaster address in Exchange Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/configure-external-postmaster-address)

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!